# How to detect intersection of 3 different colors

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image created by many polygons of different solid colors. The coordinates themselves are not given, but can be detected if necessary.

I'm looking for a way to detect all points which are the intersection of 3 or more different colors. The colors are not known in advance, might be similar to each other (e.g one might be (255, 255, 250) and another is (255, 255, 245). The specific shade doesn't matter, just the fact that it is different).

for example, in the following image a tiny star marks all the points that I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: Simply moving 3x3 matrix over the image and checking the count of distinct tuple elements can help. If more than 2 you can confirm the point in the matrix.

Comment: Can you supply additionally the image without annotations please, since they currently obscure the very thing you seek - making testing harder.

Comment: There are no such points! You might have something like: a red pixel at `(x, y)`, a blue pixel at `(x+1, y)`, and a green pixel at `(x+1, y+1)`. From my understanding of your task, this would be an "intersection". But, now, which of these three points do you want to have as an output?

Comment: 1. detect the colors (histogram?); 2. create a mask for each of the colors; 3. dilate each of the masks; 4. for each pixel, count how many masks have this pixel: if more than 1, N colors intersect there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your annotations have obscured the intersections you are trying to identify, I made a new, similar image.

[image]

Rather than trying to bend my brain around trying to deal with 3-dimensions of 8-bit RGB colour, I converted that to a single 24-bit integer and then ran a generic filter from `SciPy` and counted the number of unique colours in each 3x3 window and made a new image from that. So each pixel in the result has a brightness value equal to the number of colours in its neighbourhood. I counted the number of colours by converting the Numpy array of neighbours into a Python set - exploiting the fact that a set can only have unique numbers in it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter

# CountUnique
def CountUnique(P):
    """
    We receive P[0]..P[8] with the pixels in the 3x3 surrounding window, return count of unique values
    """
    return len(set(P))

# Open image and make into Numpy array
PILim = Image.open('patches.png').convert('RGB')
RGBim = np.array(PILim)

# Make a single channel 24-bit image rather than 3 channels of 8-bit each
RGB24 = (RGBim[...,0].astype(np.uint32)<<16) | (RGBim[...,1].astype(np.uint32)<<8) | RGBim[...,2].astype(np.uint32)

# Run generic filter counting unique colours in neighbourhood
result = generic_filter(RGB24, CountUnique, (3, 3))

# Save result
Image.fromarray(result.astype(np.uint8)).save('result.png')
```

[image]

The resultant image is shown here, with the contrast stretched so that you can see the brightest pixels at the intersections you seek.

A histogram of the values in the result image shows there are 21 pixels which have 3 unique colours in their 3x3 neighbourhood and 4,348 pixels which have 2 unique colours in their neighbourhood. You can find these by running `np.where(result==3)`, for example.

```
  Histogram:
    155631: (  1,  1,  1) #010101 gray(1)
      4348: (  2,  2,  2) #020202 gray(2)
        21: (  3,  3,  3) #030303 gray(3)
```

---

For extra fun, I had a go at programming the method suggested by @Micka and that gives the same results, code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage.morphology import dilation, disk

# Open image and make into Numpy array
PILim = Image.open('patches.png').convert('RGB')
RGBim = np.array(PILim)
h, w = RGBim.shape[0], RGBim.shape[1]

# Make a single channel 24-bit image rather than 3 channels of 8-bit each
RGB24 = (RGBim[...,0].astype(np.uint32)<<16) | (RGBim[...,1].astype(np.uint32)<<8) | RGBim[...,2].astype(np.uint32)

# Make list of unique colours
UniqueColours = np.unique(RGB24)

# Create result image
result = np.zeros((h,w),dtype=np.uint8)

# Make mask for any particular colour - same size as original image
mask = np.zeros((h,w), dtype=np.uint8)

# Make disk-shaped structuring element for morphology
selem = disk(1)

# Iterate over unique colours
for i,u in enumerate(UniqueColours):
   # Turn on all pixels matching this unique colour, turn off all others
   mask = np.where(RGB24==u,1,0)
   # Dilate (fatten) the mask by 1 pixel
   mask = dilation(mask,selem)
   # Add all activated pixels to result image
   result = result + mask

# Save result
Image.fromarray(result.astype(np.uint8)).save('result.png')
```

---

For reference, I created the image with anti-aliasing disabled in ImageMagick at the command line like this:

```
convert -size 400x400 xc:red -background red +antialias              \
  -fill blue   -draw "polygon 42,168 350,72 416,133 416,247 281,336" \
  -fill yellow -draw "polygon 271,11 396,127 346,154 77,86"          \
  -fill lime   -draw "polygon 366,260 366,400 120,400" patches.png
```

**Keywords**: Python, image, image processing, intersect, intersection, PIL/Pillow, adjacency, neighbourhood, neighborhood, neighbour, neighbor, generic, SciPy, 3x3, filter.

Comment: I have added in my rendition of the method suggested by @Micka